# print "Enter a character " a = gets if (a == 'b') puts "b was pressed" end

Tags: ruby, if-statement, compare, character, string-comparison

I am a new learner to Ruby. I also tried

```
print "Enter a character "
a = gets
if (a == "b")
  puts "b was pressed"
end
```

And this as well

```
print "Enter a character "
a = gets.to_s
if (a == 'b')
  puts "b was pressed"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed the method [`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-chomp). Change your code as below :

```
print "Enter a character "
a = gets.chomp
if (a == "b")
  puts "b was pressed"
end
```

Now run your code:

```
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~/Ruby$ ruby so.rb
Enter a character b
b was pressed
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~/Ruby$
```

Note: Your code was not working,as `a = gets` actually was assigning `"b\n"` to the variable `a`,which of course not equal to `"b"`.But using `#chomp` will do remove the `\n` from the string,you just input from command prompt and will produce the expected output.